# How can I export a template converted from a container in Proxmox?

Tags: containers, virtualization, lxc, proxmox

I have a Proxmox server, in it I created a container. I customized it,
then I converted it to a template, and I could created linked clones.

How can I export this template converted from a container so I can use it on another Proxmox server ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can backup your template on the first host, and restore the backup from the second host.